# No Java node in Categories pane in netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I want to create a Java application. I'm using Netbeans 7.1 and JDK 1.7.

When I go to File -> New Project, there is no JAVA node in categories pane. Only a standard option for creating java free form project.

What can be done?

Comment: *"Only a standard option for creating java free form project.  What can be done?"* ..Learn how to program?

Comment: very funny. I was asking if anyone knew why the java node and all other nodes( eg.web, enterprise, c/c++, soa, ruby) were absent. They should normally be present.

Comment: Reinstall Netbeans. Choose the Java SE, Java EE or All bundles.

Comment: I use Netbeans 7.1 with JDK 7 and the Java node is there.

Comment: @CostisAivalis: I tried reinstalling. Didnt work.

Comment: They should be there - maybe move your `.netbeans` directory and see if a standard configuration is recreated.

Comment: @bdecaf:Thanks, that made it happen.

Comment: tool ---> plugins ---> (tab) instaled ---> right mouseclick ---> activate, but this isn't standard way

Answer (score -1):

Go to Tools-> Java Platforms, and see if your JDK has been registered there. It could be that you have only the JRE installed (not likely unless you downloaded the OS-Independent zip), or your PATH variable does not include the JDK's bin directory. In either case, just type 'javac' into the command prompt (Start->Run->'cmd.exe'). If you get an error, but are sure you have the JDK, check Oracle's website on configuring the PATH variable.