# Can't create java application project in netbeans8.1.(ubuntu)

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-8, netbeans-8.1

I am new to NetBeans and I can't create a "Java Application" project, like shown in all tutorials. I can only create a Java Free-Form Project, but this requires a build script, which I don't have either.
Do I have to download a plugin for it and if so which plugin? Or did I download the wrong NetBeans version?
I am using ubuntu version 15 and NetBeans IDE 8.1.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAPJj.jpg screenshot.

Comment: What excactly do you mean with you can't create this project? Do you get any error message or what?

Comment: I can't/dont know how to add a build script and I can't create the "Java Application" project as shown in most tutorials. I can only create a java free-form project which requires a build script.

Comment: So you mean that you haven't any dialog for _create Java Application_ right?

Comment: Never seen that, but there's a FAQ entry with some things you may want to check/try: http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqMissingProjectCategories

Comment: Have you installed Java?

Comment: Uploaded a screenshot with the screen.

Comment: I have java jdk 8 installed. You couldn't install netbeans without specifying where java was installed.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9480499/no-java-node-in-categories-pane-in-netbeans , looks very similar. Did you already remove your userdir and/or had a look at the netbeans log as I suggested before?

Answer (score 4):

Just make sure you have JDK installed on your system. (I am pretty sure, it would be as Netbeans doesn't install if JDK is not found on your machine, but just to be sure about it). Also, You might have missed to select Java in Select Languages during installation.
To activate a feature manually:

1. Open the Tools > Plugins menu
2. Go to the Installed tab.
3. Select and activate the feature you need.
4. Return to the New Project dialog.

Visit this link for more help:

http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqMissingProjectCategories

Comment: Thanks I did a silent install and on first startup the netbeans_jdkhome was set incorrectly so all the Java stuff got deactivated but I couldn't figure out why it wasn't working after I fixed the jdkhome

Answer (score 1):

Found the plugin:
It was in the the "Ant" or the "Ant 1.9.4. Documentation 1.9.4" or Mobility plugin. I downloaded those 3 at the same time, but If I have to guess it was the Mobility plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help you. I've been working on Windows. I have Netbeans 8.1 and JDK 8 (version 1.8.0.73). When I first started with Netbeans and tried to create my first new Project it opened the New Project window with the Categories portion of the new Project screen focused on the Samples section. I also thought I couldn't create the type of project I wanted to create. If this is what is happening to you, see if you can scroll up in the Categories box. If you can, you should find Java at the top. If you click that, you should then be able to select Java Application in the Projects part of the window.